# react useEffect hook cleanup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to understand how is exactly react useEffect cleanup used and for what purpose. Could you please help me fix my code by adding the cleanup

as far as I am able to understand it's used in case of API calls in order to close a subscription. Still unable to clarify why it used and how exactly.

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoad() {
        
            try {
              
              const examSessions = await loadSessions(id);
              setSessions(examSessions);
              console.log(`examSession`,examSessions)
            } catch (e) {
            //   onError(e);
                console.log(e)
            }
        
            setIsLoading(false);
        }


        onLoad()
    }, [id])



    function loadSessions(id) {
        const result = API.get("vce", `/session/${id}`)
        return result
    }
```

Comment: I doubt, someone may explain that in more comprehensive manner than [official docs do](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect). If there's some specific detail you failed to catch, you'd better ask *smaller* question.

Comment: how do i create and clean up the subscription in this code situation? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the cleanup, your effects will continue doing whatever they were doing forever even though the component has become unmounted.

This is important for complex components that might be responsible for setting up network things like Web Socket connections or requesting data using `fetch`.  If you didn't cancel or close those, those resources would still be open and possibly sending signals.

Consider the following example where we can toggle a `Foo` component that ticks up.  With the cleanup commented out, we still see "Tick" even though it has unmounted because we don't take the time to clean up the interval.

In fact, if you re-toggle the `Foo` back on, you'll start to see even more "Tick"s in console because there are now 2+ intervals ticking about.  Imagine if that was a Web Socket and we were scheduling a new heartbeat tick every time we remounted; the server would be very angry at our apps heart palpitations.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createElement
} = React;
const {
  render
} = ReactDOM;

const Foo = () => {
  const [t, setT] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Tick");
      setT(currT => currT + 1);
    }, 1000);

    // Without the following, you will see "Tick" forever because it isn't cleaned up
    //return () => clearInterval(interval);

  }, []);

  return createElement("div", {}, t);
};

const App = () => {
  const [should, setShould] = useState(true);

  return createElement("div", null, 
    createElement("button", {
      onClick: () => setShould(currShould => !currShould)
    }, "toggle"),
    should ? createElement(Foo) : null
  );
};

render(
  createElement(App),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Compare that to the following example which ***does*** have the cleanup which ***will*** stop showing "Tick" whenever you toggle the `Foo` component.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createElement
} = React;
const {
  render
} = ReactDOM;

const Foo = () => {
  const [t, setT] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Tick");
      setT(currT => currT + 1);
    }, 1000);

    // Without the following, you will see "Tick" forever because it isn't cleaned up
    return () => clearInterval(interval);

  }, []);

  return createElement("div", {}, t);
};

const App = () => {
  const [should, setShould] = useState(true);

  return createElement("div", null, 
    createElement("button", {
      onClick: () => setShould(currShould => !currShould)
    }, "toggle"),
    should ? createElement(Foo) : null
  );
};

render(
  createElement(App),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: i see what you mean here. need some time to digest but this is actually really good

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use cleanup hook here. You are not subscribed to anything. When you subscribed in a useEffect to something and don't unsubscribe on a component destruction, this subscription will continue listening to remote source, leaching device memory and user data.

To test it, you can just attach say a click listener to a button, mount/unmount a component (without page refresh) and see in chrome dev tools how the list of subscriptions/listeners grows.

Edit:
Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
        let unmounted = false;
        async function onLoad() {
        
            try {
              
              const examSessions = await loadSessions(id);
              setSessions(examSessions);
              console.log(`examSession`,examSessions)
            } catch (e) {
            //   onError(e);
                console.log(e)
            }
        
            if(!unmounted)setIsLoading(false);
        }


        onLoad()
        return ()=> unmounted = true;
    }, [id])
```

Comment: i will defenitely try this because my application is giving me strange error messages of memory leak which i clearly do not understand... Thank you for the idea

Comment: Possibly, it's because of `setIsLoading(false);` It's possible for it to (try) run after the component is destroyed because of waiting for you api call. In that case...I edited my answer.

Comment: this is good. i will test it out. i see what you mean.